# Swift: Using Firebase Firestore database for building a shop checkout

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently building an app where the user can order custom printed postcards.

For that I need a backend database of all the orders. I'm trying to realize that with Firebase.

When a user places a new order I need to perform three steps:

1. Create a new entry in a Firestore database
2. Upload image assets to Firebase Cloud Storage
3. Pay (Braintree)

**My problem:**

With Firestores realtime approach I can't find an event that clearly tells me that the order entry was successfully written to my Firestore backend or that there was an error. From what I found Firestore persists new documents locally on the device until it is able to sync with the server.

But for starting the payment process (or showing an error) I need a clear event. Is there an approach to build these kind of "shop checkouts" with Firestore? The alternative would be to use Firebase Cloud Functions.

Comment: What's being asked appears to be covered in the documentation with an example [Add a Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), so maybe you're asking something more or the question needs clarity?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect when the data was written on the server, you can attach a completion listener/callback. For example as shown in the documentation on [writing a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document):

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData([
    "name": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "country": "USA"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document on server: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written on server!")
    }
}
```

If you need tighter guarantees, consider [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) as those will simply not complete unless the device is connected to the Firestore backend.

Comment: Hey @Frank, thank you for the support.
My problem with the code from your example is, that there was never an error within the completion. But sending the data via a transaction worked out perfectly.

Comment: What you're describing is correct: the completion handler will not fail, as Firestore doesn't consider not having an internet connection (as that is typically transient). So if you only want to start the operation when there is a connection, a transaction is indeed one way to do that.